# CSS - Stop text dropping below icon

Tags: css

I have a jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/34tdwve7/1/

Sorry I know this is simple but my brain won't work.

I have div's containing text and an icon to it's left

When the text is longer than the container it drops below the icon

I need to stop this text going below the icon like in the bottom example.

The bottom example uses height on the icon each isn't dynamic - I won't know the height.

```
    <div class="block">

       <div class="item">
           <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
           <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut</div>
       </div>

       <div class="item">
           <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
           <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
       </div>

       <div class="item">
           <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
           <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </div>
       </div> 

    </div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/34tdwve7/2/ is that what you want? @ttmt

Comment: Simple: `.item > div { margin-left: 24px; padding-left: 12px; }` -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/34tdwve7/3/ But, why not use a bullted list for that purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add:

```
.item {
    margin-bottom: 15px; 
    padding-left: 20px;
}

i {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 0 -20px;
}
```